# Eclipse plugin issue

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse in windows laptop. Once opened the eclipse Am trying to exit or restart. That time i got the error

> problem occurred when invoking code from plug-in
>   org.eclipse.ui.workbench

.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: `when invoking code from plug-in` ???? & Can you paste your complete statement of error?

Comment: No..Due to slow performance of eclipse, am trying to restart..

Comment: Error: "problem occurred when invoking code from plug-in org.eclipse.ui.workbench"

Comment: off the topic but IntelliJ is fabulous for android developing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make sure that you shut down eclipse properly.
(1)First of all you need should try this
**myeclipse.exe -clean** 
or
Alternatively, add the following line to the `myeclipse.ini` file, near the top:
`-clean` 
(2)If problem is still occuring then Just create a new workspace and then import all project files in it. It will surely work :)
But if it still not resolved then
(3)*You need to reinstall the eclipse*